# How to scroll through tkinter widgets that were defined inside of a function?

Tags: python, tkinter, scrollbar

I created a main root with two frames.

- One frame is for program toolbar.
- The other frame is for a canvas where data will be displayed and for a scrollbar widget.
- Inside of the canvas is a third smaller frame which will be used for scrolling trough data.

However, when I try to define new widgets inside of a function call, the scroll button loses its functionality. That smaller frame is scrollable only if I define these widgets in the top level of the code.

I used a simple for loop to create labels just for testing.

Could anyone tell what I am doing wrong?

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk



#Creating main window
root = Tk()
root.resizable(width=False, height=False)



#Defining Background

toolbar = Frame(root, width=613, height=114)
toolbar.grid(row=0, column=0)

background_frame = Frame(root, width=615, height=560)
background_frame.grid(row=1, column=0)

background = Canvas(background_frame, width=615, height=560)
background.pack(side=LEFT, fill=BOTH, expand=1)

scroll_bar = ttk.Scrollbar(background_frame, orient=VERTICAL, command=background.yview)
scroll_bar.pack(side=RIGHT, fill=Y)

background.configure(yscrollcommand=scroll_bar.set)
background.bind('<Configure>', lambda e:background.configure(scrollregion = background.bbox('all')))

second_frame = Frame(background)
background.create_window(150,100, window=second_frame, anchor='nw')


def confirm1():
    
    
    for x in range(100): 
        Label(second_frame, text = x ).grid(row=x, column=1)




show_labels = Button(toolbar, text= "Show labels", fg="black", command=confirm1)
show_labels.grid(row=0, column=2)

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Why are you creating your window at position `150, 100`? Usually people use `0, 0`.

Comment: I don't want the data to start appearing in the very corner. But I might change that, it's not that important.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to to update the background canvas' `scrollregion` whenever you add widgets to the `second_frame`. That's easy to do by binding to *that* frame's `<Configure>` event.

Here's a complete version of your code with a couple of lines added (`# WHERE INDICATED`) to do that:

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk

#Creating main window
root = Tk()
root.resizable(width=False, height=False)

#Defining Background
toolbar = Frame(root, width=613, height=114)
toolbar.grid(row=0, column=0)

background_frame = Frame(root, width=615, height=560)
background_frame.grid(row=1, column=0)

background = Canvas(background_frame, width=615, height=560)
background.pack(side=LEFT, fill=BOTH, expand=1)

scroll_bar = ttk.Scrollbar(background_frame, orient=VERTICAL, command=background.yview)
scroll_bar.pack(side=RIGHT, fill=Y)

background.configure(yscrollcommand=scroll_bar.set)
# NOT NEEDED
#background.bind('<Configure>',
#                lambda e: background.configure(scrollregion=background.bbox('all')))

second_frame = Frame(background)
background.create_window(150,100, window=second_frame, anchor='nw')

# ADDED
second_frame.bind('<Configure>',
                  lambda e: background.configure(scrollregion=background.bbox('all')))

def confirm1():
    for x in range(100):
        Label(second_frame, text=x).grid(row=x, column=1)

show_labels = Button(toolbar, text="Show labels", fg="black", command=confirm1)
show_labels.grid(row=0, column=2)

root.mainloop()
```

Result after clicking button and scrolling the canvas region:

[image: screenshot showing all widgets are in scrolled region now]

Comment: Thank you so much Martineau, your solution works great!! Could you provide me with some sources where I could learn more about similar problems and topics?

Comment: Rastko: You're welcome. Sorry I must say no, I can't provide you with any definitive resources about `tkinter` because I know of none. It's very poorly documented and not "pythonic" in many ways. Unfortunately it's the de-facto GUI library for the language. That said, one of the best *references* I've found (which is now getting to be a bit dated) is the [Tkinter 8.5 reference: a GUI for Python](https://anzeljg.github.io/rin2/book2/2405/docs/tkinter/index.html).

Comment: Thank you, I will see if I can find something there. All the best